# Open website in python with URL parameters

Tags: python

I'm new in python an i try to open a webbrowser with an URL and some URL params.
My Plattform is a current Version of RaspberryPi OS with Python 3.
Example:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new("myurl.com?param1=1&param2=2")
```

But now the webbrowser opens:

```
myurl.com%3Fparam1=1&param2=2
```

I tried "?" "??" and '?' in the string, but nothing worked for me =(

Now my question: How can i open an URL with URL Parameters. It seems like the python webbrowser is parsing my ? on the wrong time
...

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Just to make it clear:
I want to open a new Chromium window with this example Link. The python script just calculates some URL Params for the website.

Edit2: The Problem was, that the html file was on my local filesystem. I forgot to add "file://" in front of the Path.

Better example woud be:

Wrong:

```
/home/html/sample.html?param1=1
```

Correct

```
file:///home/html/sample.html?param1=1
```

Comment: What is your end goal? Is it to call an api with params or is it to scrape from a website? If you are trying to scrape with params i'd suggest BS4 over web-browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to open a website in a new browser window and the python programm should calculate some parameters for this website.

Comment: @esqew That is exactly why I started my *comment* with a question. And it's also why I didn't choose to answer the question but instead comment. If you have an answer, please, by all means, post it below so it can be criticized like an answer, and not in the comments where questions should be asked.

Comment: @esqew I'd also like to add that I was referring to "If you are trying to scrape with params" with BS4, because of the lack of information provided in the question. "Evaluation and execution" nor do I see OP talking about that or needing that in the question, so I am not too sure why you would implicate it (just got an answer now because of my question).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Shame on ME. I made the example too easy and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the html file was on my local filesystem. I forgot to add "file://" in front of the Path.

Better example woud be:

Wrong:

```
/home/html/sample.html?param1=1
```

Correct

```
file:///home/html/sample.html?param1=1
```